# Postgresql Performance tip for scattered data

Tags: performance, postgresql

I am trying to improve the performance of my database, which simplified set-up is the following :

**EDIT**

- One table with 3 rows (id_device, timestamp, data) with a composite btree index (id_device, timestamp)
- 1k devices sending data every minute

The insert are quite fast, since PostgreSQL merely writes the rows in the order they are received. However, when trying to get many data with consecutive timestamp of a given device, the query is not so fast. The way I understand it is that due to the way the data is collected, there is never more than one row of a given device on each page of the table. Therefore, if I want to get 10k data with consecutive timestamp of a given device, PostgreSQL has to fetch 10k pages from disk. Besides, since this operation can be done on any of the 1k devices, those pages are not going to be kept in RAM.

I have tried to CLUSTER the table, and it indeed solve the performance issue, but this operation is incredibly long (~1 day) and it locks the entire table, so I discarded this solution.

I have read about the partitionning, but that would mean a lot of scripting if I need to add a new table every time a new devices is connected, and it seems to me a bit bug-prone.

I am rather confident in the fact that this set-up is not particularly original, so is there an advice I could use?

Thanks for reading,
Guillaume

Comment: If your query checks only the timestamp, you should add an index only on timestamp.

Comment: I have edited the question because I had oversimplified the set-up. There is also some data to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your index also has low selectivity, because you're indexing device_id first (which are only 1000 different) and not timestamp first.

Depends on what you do with the data you fetch, but maybe the solution could be batching the operation, such as fetching the data for a predetermined period and processing data for all 1000 devices in one go.

Comment: Batching the operation is indeed what I am considering, together with storing the processed data in another table. I am thinking of a daily job, that would store for each devices the list of data of the day as one row, so that those data would stay close together. However, my question is really : am I using PostgreSQL correctly or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think there's much to do here. You are storing data in PostgreSQL as it arrives, and if you can't shard it, eg. according to device_id, then the only sensible solution is to process data in batch, since it doesn't make much difference if you touch every 1000-th record or all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not know about sharding, I will have a look at that.